# CMake with OpenCV Mac (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, opencv, installation

I would like to install opencv without using Macports. Also, I don't want the files to be in `local` folder. What I did as following

```
cd opencv-2.4.8
mkdir _build _install
cd _build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../_install ..
make
```

I got the following errors

```
[ 34%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/bitstrm.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentOrder", referenced from:
      _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentPattern", referenced from:
      _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentRow", referenced from:
      _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentSpeed", referenced from:
```

and the end

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.8.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is wrong with my approach?

Info:

Mac OS X 10.9.3 (OS X Mavericks)

OpenCV-2.4.8

I've updated the command line tools for OS X Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

install ffmpeg or build opencv without ffmpeg if you don't use it.
-D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF